# Error in substring arguments when calling mapply with regmatches as argument

Tags: regex, r, text-mining, mapply

[![enter image description here][1]][1]The following code compiles a data frame of reviews of businesses and aims to extract the business name from each row.  There are no matches with the regular expression in the first 14 rows, I've noticed, and there's no problem there.  As soon as I include the first row with a match (15 in this case), I receive the following error.

```
Error in substring(x[ind], so, eo) : invalid substring arguments
```

It seems like the problem is between regexpr sending the results to index.list, and regmatches being unable to use the index.list as the proper argument.

Note that when I run just the 15th row without the mapply, I obtain the proper result.  If there is a more efficient way to get the results of regmatches into a new column in lieu of mapply, please let me know.  I cannot use stringr or other packages (school assignment).

```
require("tm")
reviews <- VCorpus(DirSource("C:/...../reviews"))

all.reviews <-   data.frame(text=unlist(sapply(reviews,'[',"content")),stringsAsFactors=F)

data <- all.reviews[10:15,]

index.list <- mapply(regexpr, "(?<=Review of )(\\w+ )+(?=-\\s*   [A-Z])", data, perl=T))
rest.names <- mapply(regmatches, data, index.list)
```

I am unable to attach an image, so here is a sample from the 15th row of all.reviews data.frame (which has dim 90 X 1):

*Via S.'s Review of Good To Go -Bronx (4/5) on Yelp. Good To Go 22 reviews Rating Details Categories: Restaurants American (Traditional)Restaurants Italian American (Traditional); Italian [Edit] 1894 Eastchester Rd Bronx; NY 10461 (718) 829-2222 http://www.good2gorestaurant.com Explore the menu Add Photos Hours: Mon-Thu; Sun 10 am - 10pm Fri-Sat 10 am - 11 pm Good for Kids: Yes Accepts Credit Cards: Yes Parking: Valet; Garage; Street;Private Lot Attire: Casual Good for Groups: Yes Price Range: $ Takes Reservations: Yes*

The expected output for the function is a vector with 90 elements, where each element is the restaurant name (or a blank if nothing was extracted from the string, since there are other review formats that I will address with additional regexpr statements).  We would expect to see "Good to Go" in the 15th index.

Comment: post a sample input along with expected output.

Comment: Avinash Raj, I included a sample and a description of the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A classmate of mine came up with an answer.  Turns out that the last argument of mapply should be a list, not a dataframe, so lapply does the trick:

```
data.mult <- all.reviews[1:15,]    

index.list <- lapply(data.mult,function(x) {
regexpr("(?<=Review of )([A-z-'\\s*]+)+\\w+(?=\\s*-\\s*[A-Z])",x,perl=T)})

rest.names <- mapply(regmatches, data.mult, index.list)
```